# Did set fuses incorrect: 328p is expecting a oscillator now - how to reset?

Tags: bootloader, atmega, avrdude

I had some circuit boards made for a universal sensor. Basically it is a 328p on a standalone basis with some sensors. Well, they all work, I was able to write the bootloader using an arduino uno, but with two 328p I did not pay attention.

I specified the Pro Mini 8mhz, which has a crystal, as the board when I wrote the bootloader. Well on my board I did not provide a crystal, it runs with the internal clock.

The two 328p expect now however a quartz. I can't set fuses anymore and I can't write a bootloader.

```
avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000
avrdude: Yikes!  Invalid device signature.
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.
```

Sidenote: Given that I was able to write the bootloader on the other 328p's we can exclude a wiring issue.

What possibilities do I have to write a bootloader on it?

Ok, yes somehow to fiddle a quartz on it, but otherwise?

Comment: This is Arduino?  You may want to mention that, if so.   Note also that StackOverflow has listed several 'related' questions; one of them may help you.  Looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29100297/yikes-invalid-device-signature?rq=1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37256234/arduino-burning-bootloader-without-external-crystal?rq=1 might help.

Comment: Just found myself another idea after hours of googling: an alternative isp
https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Learning_System_Guides/tree/master/ArduinoISP/ArduinoISP

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found an excellent answer:

use ArduinoISP2 (an alternative ArduinoISP) to burn it. The difference is that on PIN9 you get an oscillator signal you can use on your target 328p on XTAL1.

https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Learning_System_Guides/tree/master/ArduinoISP

Hope this helps everyone.

Comment: Thank you for coming back and explaining your find; it may help someone else.  Remember to come back and mark your self-answer as accepted, if it worked and solved your problem.